# Node JS: Code Refactor with almost similar codes in different forEach

Tags: node.js, refactoring

Say, I have some code which looks like follows:-

```
objects1.forEach(function check(o1) {
    if (o1.name === object.name) {
        object.name = object.name + objectType;
    }
});

objects2.forEach(function ifNameMatch(o2) {
    if (o2.name === object.name) {
        object.name = object.name + objectType;
    }
});
```

Is there any way I could replace this 2 forEach by one or write it in the more better way?

Any suggestion that you could give would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for answer with ES5 or ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would create a generator for each object I have to do it, if its a repetitive process, then I would return a function that would process collections which is `objects1` or `objects2` in your scenario.

```
let nameMatchGenerator = (object, objectType)  => {
return (collections) => { 
  return collections.forEach(collection) => {
    collection.forEach(o => {
      if (o.name === object.name) {
        object.name = object.name + objectType;
      }
    })
  }
}
let nameMatch = (object, objectType);
nameMatch([objects1, objects2]) // you can use this function to repeat 
                             // the process for as many collections
```